# Dynamic sub-field assignation

Tags: php

I have some difficulties to explain my problem, some code is better than a long text:

```
<?php

$n = new stdClass();
$f = 'field[0][0]';
$n->$f = 1;
var_dump($n);
```

The current result:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["field[0][0]"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

The desired result:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["field"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eval('$n->'.$f.'=1;');
```

additional to this,
please check `$f` is from **TRUSTABLE** source

Answer (score 1):

How about using:

```
$n = new stdClass();
$f = 'field';
$n->$f = array(array(1));
var_dump($n);
```

Comment: I needed that the sub-fields is dynamically created. It's for import a CSV file in drupal 7 with a mapping like: `$mapping = array('First-name' => 'field_firstname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"]');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = new stdClass();
$f = 'field';
$n->$f = array(array(1));
var_dump($n);

object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["field"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } } }
```